# Internet Explorer 11 downgrading document mode

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, x-ua-compatible

With developer mode open, i visit a site A, and see that document mode is set to Edge (default). When following a link on that site to site B, I see that IE automatically downgrades the document mode to 5(!), breaking the site. Furthermore, it's not possible anymore to change document mode to 10 or 9 (it was on site A), rather only 5,6,7 and edge are available.

Site B has this tag set in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Internet Explorer has no compability mode settings for Site B.

I am completely lost here, what could cause IE to downgrade its document mode like this?

Comment: The developer tools tend to give an explanation why a particular mode was selected.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that on my IE11. Unfortunatly, on the IE11-browsers having this problem (which is an old, intranet version), it does *not* give the explanation ...

Comment: What is the doctype of Site B?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this may be a `<!DOCTYPE>` issue. With IE 11 document modes are considered deprecated and Microsoft is using the `<!DOCTYPE>` to render the page.

If a site has the following `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration then it will render in Standard mode:

> HTML 4.0 and higher
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
>
> XHTML with or without a system identifier
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic10.dtd">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`
>
> Unknown
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html>`

If a site has the following `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration then it will render in "Almost Standards" mode (standards mode in IE7):

> XHTML Transitional or Frameset
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhmlt1-transitional.dtd">`
>
> HTML 4.0 or HTML 4.01 Transitional or Frameset with a system identifier
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">`

If a site has the following `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration then it will render in Quirks mode (aka IE 5):

> HTML 4 and lower, or no DOCTYPE
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`
>
> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`
>
> None

([Source of above list.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

If Site B has a no doctype or one from the last list, it will render in Quirks mode which is equal to IE 5.